# Database questions, on topic?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Recently I've been having to research database indexing which has led me to find a large amount of answers on the topic on StackOverflow.

However when I had [my own question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/63131/why-do-indexed-views-not-permit-non-unique-clustered-indexes) that needed asking. I was unsure of which StackExchange site it best belonged on. Although, in the end, I did opt for Database Administrators.

[Which site for database design questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/596/which-site-for-database-design-questions)

This Meta discussion does suggest that questions on Indexing would be on-topic for StackOverflow how ever as pointed out by gbn in the answers, the other answers are now quite out of date.

Although my assumption is that DBA is the correct place, due to the fact there is a migration path to the site, it seems Meta lacks a categoric answer currently.
What is the actually the current policy?

If I had asked my question on StackOverflow, would it have been correct to flag it for migration?

Comment: Going to agree with you there Gnat, did not come across that one. I'm going to stick my close vote in to instead of deleting the question for future searches.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194495/165773 - your case seems to match section 1 there "This is best possible outcome..." :)

Answer (score 1):

I would say all things that can be **coded**, like stored procedures, UDFs, connecting db through some language, and things which require the some corrections in SQL queries should be asked in StackOverflow.

Rest of the things, like how the db design should be, how should it be maintained, creating backups, etc.. should be asked in DBA site.

In your case,your question isn't about coding. Its about theory. So I think it would have been migrated, if you had asked about it on StackOverflow

Comment: You are right on about the difference in topics between the sites. Just one note to add; [DBA.SE] also generally requires specific, practical problems for questions. So theory and opinions won't generally work well.